# Comparing tails of polynomial functions

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Suppose that $P(x) = a_m x^m + \dots + a_0$ and $Q(x) = b_n x^n + \dots + b_0$ are two polynomials, with $m > n > 1$ and $a_m > b_n > 0$. Suppose that $P$ has $m$ distinct real roots $y_1<\dots<y_m$ and $Q$ has $n$ distinct real roots $z_1<\dots<z_n$.

Is the following claim true: 
$P(x) - Q(x)$ is strictly increasing for all $x \geq \max \{y_m, z_n\}$.

Note: I have a missing step in a larger proof, which would be fixed by a result like this. In my particular application, I have a bit more specific polynomials and with every numerical example I can come up with the result seems to hold, but I think this result should be more general.

Comment: Try $P(x) = 2 x^3 + 3$, $Q(x) = x^2$.  Neither $P$ nor $Q$ has positive roots, but $P-Q$ is decreasing on  $(0,1/3)$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. In my application, both polynomials have only real (and in fact $m$ and $n$ distinct) roots. I updated the question.

Comment: OK, try $P(x) = 2 x (x+1)(x+1/3)$ and $Q(x) = x (x+1)$.  Note that $P'(0)-Q'(0) = -1/3$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I think that this proves that my conjecture was wrong. I'll have to find another angle. If you want to, you can state it as an answer, so that I can approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $P(x) = 2 x (x+1)(x+1/3)$ and $Q(x) = x(x+1)$.  Note that $P'(0) - Q'(0) = -1/3$.